# How to delete a values from json file and pass it as request in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I am learning Cypress and automating API tests. I have a JSON file in the fixtures folder and I want to pass this JSON file as a request body.

```
{
  "name": "Harry",
  "email": "hello@cypress.io",
  "mobile": "1234"
}
```

so if I want to change the mobile value to something else then I can do like

```
cy.fixture('request.json').then((requestBody) => {
      requestBody.mobile = '5678'
      cy.request({
        url: requestUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        body: requestBody
    })
})
```

If I want to delete the mobile value and just want to pass name and email from request.json then can I do this from the same file or I have to create a separate file. Is it possible in cypress?

```
 requestBody.mobile.delete() //something like this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to omit the `mobile` property:

```
cy.fixture('request.json').then(({ mobile, ...requestBody }) =>
  cy.request({
    url: requestUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    body: requestBody
  })
)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alekse I am using ```delete mobile ``` this is also working. Not sure which one is better

Comment: In this example doesn't really matter I guess. The difference is that `delete` mutates the object